# Running a for loop to print type of input boxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop

I have this idea that I wanted to try out. I have a form which has a certain number of input elements inside it. I want to run a function that will print out the type of the input elements using two for loops. Here is the code that I tried out

```
                  function check(){         
                     var i = document.forms.length;
                     var j = document.forms[i-1].elements.length;
                    //alert(i);
                   //  alert(j);
                    for (var k=0; k<=i;k++){
                    //alert(l);
                         for (var l=0;l<=j;l++){  
                          //alert(l);
                          alert(document.forms[k].elements[l].type);
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

The code only prints out the type of the first element in the form. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: are you open to jquery?i think you can do this using one loop in pure js also

Comment: No I want to do it pure JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get all the forms in your page, loop thru each forms, inside first loop get the elements specific to the form which is currently being iterated, loop thru the elements and get the type,  try doing:

```
var frms = document.forms;
for(var f = 0; f < frms.length; f++ ) {
    var elems = frms[f].elements;
    for(var e = 0; e < elems.length; e++ ) {
        console.log( elems[e].type );
    }
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4bHh/)

Comment: some comments would be great!!+1

Comment: Your code works. Thanks, But I have a doubt why doesn't the code work if I assign frms = document.forms.length instead of frms =document.forms

Comment: @Bazinga777 thats because you are getting form elements outside the loop, due to which it returns undefined

Comment: @Sudhir Can you explain it a bit more? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)?

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("form input");
for(var i in elems) {
  console.log(elems[i].type);
}
```

If not, you need to count the elements for the form inside your first `for` loop:

```
function check(){         
  var i = document.forms.length;       
  for (var k=0; k<i;k++){
    // Check the element length here
    var j = document.forms[k].elements.length;
    for (var l=0;l<j;l++){  
      alert(document.forms[k].elements[l].type);
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script and works well with the following modifications:

First Loop `for (var k=0; k<=i-1;k++)`{

Second Loop `for (var l=0;l<=j-1;l++){`

Otherwise you have an error cause all loops are executed +1 times.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/REb64/

```
      function check(){   
        for (var i=0; i < document.forms.length; i++){
          for (var j=0; j < document.forms[i].elements.length; j++){
            alert(document.forms[i].elements[j].type);
          }
        }
      }
```